# Confused about the solution to this integral

Tags: integration

[image]

I am confused as to how the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \theta \cdot x^{-3/2}dx$$

was evaluated as: $$2 \cdot \theta^{1/2}$$

with $x^{-1/2}$ in the equation and $x = \infty$, shouldn't that set everything to $0$ ?

Comment: Please write up your integral in the question so it is self-contained.

Comment: The Help menu will help you format math on this site.

Comment: $2\theta^{1/2}$ is certainly absurd (assuming $\theta$ is a constant). The problem is not as $x\to\infty$, but as $x\to0$, the integrand blows up, and the improper integral does not converge. Who says that integral comes out to $2\sqrt{\theta}$? Are you sure that's what it says?

Comment: Are you still here, L. Chen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\theta\ $ is constant he equation $\int_o^\infty\theta\cdot x^{-3/2} \, dx $ can be written as:

$$\theta\cdot\int_o^\infty\ x^{-3/2} \, dx$$

Now $$\int x^{n} \,dx = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

Therefore,
$$\int x^{-3/2} \, dx=\dfrac{x^{\dfrac{-3}2+1}}{\dfrac{-3}2+1}+C= \dfrac{x^{-1/2}}{\dfrac{-1}2}$$

$$\int_o^\infty\theta\cdot x^{-3/2} \, dx=-2\theta\cdot[x^{-1/2}]_o^\infty$$

Now from here, I assume that the lower limit is $\theta$ instead of $0$

In that case
$$\int_o^\infty\theta\cdot x^{-3/2} \, dx=-2\theta\cdot[x^{-1/2}]_\theta^\infty$$
$$=-2\theta\cdot[0-\theta^{-1/2}] (\, since \, \dfrac 1{x}_{x->\infty}=0)$$
$$=2\cdot\theta^{1/2}$$

**So, the lower limit should be $\theta$ instead of $0$**